# I can't make a function call another one - Sending a Discord message on Google Sheet, with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, discord

I'm trying to create a Google Sheet that works with Discord.
On Google Sheets, you can add some script with "Apps Script".

The project is the following:
It's a social media post planner, where people can write their ideas.

In column, C, there's the text that is a draft.
When the draft is ready to be reviewed by the manager, the writer can check the box in column D, and it will send a Discord Message (through a Discord Webhook) in a channel, tagging the manager that a new post is available to review.

The script works with 2 functions:

1. onEdit(e); that will check every time if a cell is edited
2. postToDiscord(); that sends the message

If:

1. the cell in column C is empty and the box is ticked (by mistake for example), a pop-up will appear and say "empty draft"[example of onEdit working fine if the cell is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqDeR.png)
2. the cell isn't empty, it should call a function: postToDiscord(), and execute the function [test to see if there is some text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBNsI.png)

When I execute manually the postToDiscord function it does this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRtGA.png)

The issue is, individually, each function works, but when I mix them together, it doesn't do anything.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range,
      col = range.getColumn(),
      row = range.getRow(),
      edited_value = e.value,
      ss = e.range.getSheet();
 
  //check if the box isn't ticked by accident to avoid spam
  if (col == 4 && edited_value == "TRUE" && ss.getRange("C"+row).getValue() == "") {
    Browser.msgBox("Empty draft!");
  }
  //execute the postToDiscord function if the draft cell is not empty
  else if (col == 4 && edited_value == "TRUE" && ss.getRange("C"+row).getValue() !== "") {     
    Browser.msgBox("The text is:" +ss.getRange("C"+row).getValue());
    postToDiscord();
  }
  else{
  }
}

//the function that manage discord messages
function postToDiscord() {
  const url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/[url]";
      
  const message = {
    content: "hi there"
    }

  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': message
    }
    
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Are any superheroes among you?

I'm willing to have the postToDiscord work when the conditions are good in onEdit(e).

I tried things on other posts and it didn't work.

I might misunderstood them because I never coded before, I just wanna learn some stuff for fun and create it for my company

And sorry in advance for the mistakes!

Have a good one!

Comment: onEdit triggers are simple triggers and  they cannot perform operation that require permission

Answer (score 1):

Try using an installable trigger:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  let v = e.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    if (v == "") {
      e.source.toast("Empty draft!");
    } else {
      e.source.toast("The text is:" + v);
      postToDiscord();
    }
  }
}


function createInstallableTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so with what you gave me, I do remplace my onEdit(e) but I keep the postToDiscord?

Comment: Yes and you create an installable trigger